# Why embedding an iframe pushes down a sidebar?

Tags: spring-boot, layout, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I am building a simple static website. I am using Spring Boot, Thymeleaf Layout Dailect and Bootstrap 4. In my layout.html I have a row in which I have a content and a sidebar. I have 2 photos in my sidebar, in all of views they appear on the right side. However when I try to embed an iframe with a google map or with a facebook page the sidebar gets pushed down. I tried a few different things like changing the size of iframe to minimum etc. but I am unable to keep my sidebar on the right side. Please can anyone suggest a solution?

Below is my layout.html:

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid" th:replace="fragments/navigation :: navigation"></div>
<div class="container-fluid" id="mainContent">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div layout:fragment="content"></div>
        </div>          
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div th:replace="fragments/sidebar :: sidebar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="container-fluid" th:replace="fragments/footer :: footer"></div>
```

Below is my sidebar.html:

```
<body>

<div th:fragment="sidebar">
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <img src="/img/ai-ki-do.png" alt="Logo" style="width: 330px;"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <img src="/img/ueshiba-laughter.jpg" alt="Logo"
                    style="width: 330px;" ></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Below is my content:

```
<body>

<div layout:fragment="content">

<p>Thank you for your interest in Seishinkan. Please get in touch via our Facebook page.  We look forward to hearing from you.</p>

<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FSeishinkan-Aikido-Dojo-389984175129276%2F&tabs=timeline&width=340&height=500&small_header=false&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId" data-adapt-container-width="true"></iframe>
</div>

</body>
```

Normal sidebar's behaviour - a white picture 'Ai Ki Do' and a dark picture on the right side :

[image]

The sidebar pushed down after embedding the iframe:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing a new row and column within:

```
<div layout:fragment="content"></div>
```

worked for me.

```
<div layout:fragment="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="dojo-page" class="col-md-12">
            <div id="fb-frame" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="600" height="450"
                    frameborder="0" style="border: 0"
                    src="path-for-google-map-location"
                    allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
<iframe src="https://www.w3schools.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
<div>
    another one
</div>
</div>
```

For some reason when I remove the col classes from the divs and keep them in a row, the two pieces don't go below each other

Have you tried inspecting the element and editing your css classes in the browser while in developer mode?
I had the same problem before and all I did was mess around with the code in the console until it eventually moved the way I wanted it to.